# Android Timer Schedule

Tags: android, timer, task, scheduled-tasks, android-timer

Following is the code snippet which I am using in my project to schedule a task

```
mTimer = new Timer();
mTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

 @Override
 public void run() {
  //Do Something
 }

}, interval, interval);
```

This works fine. I get event after mentioned interval. But this fails to send any event if date is set smaller than current from settings.

Does any one know why this behavior is happening?

Comment: Elaborate your question

Comment: if timer is set and date is changed from settings to lower than current date, it fails to give callback

Comment: but why a timer should run for lower than current date?? Why not you just disable selection of date less than current date?

Comment: did you mean from phone's settings??

Comment: i did mention settings in my comment above and now have added in question as well

Comment: Using `Timer` in Android is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: One thing I suggest that you should get current date using system settings. In that case if system date changes it will also change for your code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Timer` fails when you change the system clock because [it's based on `System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Timer.java), which is not monotonic.

`Timer` is not an Android class.  It's a Java class that exists in the Android API to support existing non-Android libraries.  It's almost always a bad idea to use a `Timer` in your new Android code.  Use a `Handler` for timed events that occur within the lifetime of your app's activities or services.  [`Handler` is based on `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/os/Handler.java), which *is* monotonic.  Use an [Alarm](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) for timed events that should occur even if your app is not running.

Comment: Perfect!!, just what i needed. I solved my problem using handler already, but was curious to find what went wrong when used timer in first place! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.. this will help you..

```
Timer t;
seconds = 10;

public void startTimer() {
        t = new Timer();
        //Set the schedule function and rate
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (seconds == 0) {
                            t.cancel();
                           seconds = 10;
                      // DO SOMETHING HERE AFTER 10 SECONDS
                       Toast.makeText(this,"Time up",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        seconds -= 1;
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: i need reason why it is not working when i am changing date to lower than current